# Microsoft 365 subscribers to share OneDrive storage

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, onedrive

We have Microsoft 365 family account that allows 6 simultaneous users. Is it possible to have single OneDrive storage across the family? Mom and Dad may not be too computer savvy, and when Sis puts some pictures or documents, it would be really nice that it automatically shows on their local hard drive.

Even if it means that there is 1TB total storage, rather than 1TB per person, it would still be fine (at this time we use 20GB, so it's a long way to go)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Anyone you share your subscription benefits with, will get their own OneDrive storage.

They can't access files or folders on your personal OneDrive storage, though you can share files with them if you want.

We can't control everyone's storage capacity

Comment: Thank you. Having one account share pretty much everything; and allowing others edit permissions is how we do it today.